# Vector transfer speed in AIR Java extension

Tags: java, android, performance, actionscript-3, air

I am developing an AIR application targeting Android OS, using flex 4.6.0 + AIR 14.0 sdk. What application generally does is take a vector of Numbers containing 2048 elements, then uses algorithm to produce one Number from given vector, and then does some drawing based on result - and it repeats the process every 100ms

The thing is that performances of mentioned algorithm are not as good as I wanted, it often works between 50ms and 100ms, but in some situations it can even go above, and I have about 50-60ms for that processing.
So, I tried to make Java native extension that would do the complex calculations because I thought it will be faster than as3(I read that C is 10 times faster, but C extension is available only on iOS).
The thing that makes me problems is the speed of the extension, because it appears to be much slower, and extension is supposed to be used to speed up things.

Strange thing is that if I call extension and return array length it finishes for 1-2ms, but when I copy all array elements from AS3 object to Java double[], it needs about 700-800ms, and this is what bothers me. I thought that all data is transferred when extension Java method starts, but why then calling

args[0].getElementAt[0].getAsDouble()

for 2048 lasts so long, am I doing something wrong, does anybody know how does data transfer between air and extensions work in detail? 
Or if anybody knows better way to solve this problem I would be really grateful.

Here are some helpful links
[Android extension API reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSff7e9115a8550eef64893a0c132502c6a64-8000.html) and
[Extension code tutorial](http://www.digitalprimates.net/author/nweber/2012/04/10/building-a-native-extension-part-4/) - i did everything based on this tutorial, but it is much simpler than my code, so I'm posting this.

Comment: I remember I played with native extensions long time ago and had similar issue. I think that the communication between actionscript code and native extension is not that speedy.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Yeah, that was my main concern when I started working with this, but entering java extension method is fast and args unpacking is slow, and I expected vice versa situation :)

Comment: Are you sure that your algorithm in Actionscript is well optimized? It may be worth trying to make it better. Also, are you using fixed size Vector? It may be a bit faster.

Comment: use workers, btw 2048 is really not a lot of number, as3 can loop through that in no time so your 'algorithm' must be really slow.

Comment: It is a small number, but I need to do some real time fourier's transformations, and also read microphone, play sound and draw some graphics every 100ms. I found this [fft implementation for as3](http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/an-even-faster-as3-fft/), it looks good, but it still doesn't give me acceptable results as it often lasts more than 50ms on average android phones.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I found the answer to the question about transfer speed from AIR to Android extension, but it still doesn't solve my problem.

Transfer of arrays takes some time because it is done via FREObject classes, and I optimized this part by making CSV string from array and passing that string to extension. If i only read length of a string in extension and return result, it finishes in couple of ms.

But, conversion of string's to double takes a lot of time. I know that Java implementation of parseDouble() is slow, so I tried some other libraries I found and got increase in speed, but still it's above 150ms. So it appears that Java part of the story is the problem, which I expected the least. Parsing long's and int's should be much faster, which appears to be true after some tests, so I'll try to see if it is possible to work with those types.

Answer (score 1):

> But, conversion of string's to double takes a lot of time. I know that Java implementation of parseDouble() is slow, so I tried some other libraries I found and got increase in speed, but still it's above 150ms. So it appears that Java part of the story is the problem, which I expected the least. Parsing long's and int's should be much faster, which appears to be true after some tests, so I'll try to see if it is possible to work with those types.

You can make it much faster, if you can do on the other side a thing corresponding this:

```
 double x = Double.longBitsToDouble(readLong());
```

You pass a `long` and reinterpret its bits as double. On a normal JVM, it's an intrinsic, just a move from a normal register to a floating-point register, pretty fast. On Android, I don't know.

Parsing `long` is surely faster, but you could possibly make it even faster by avoiding `Character.digit`, which deals with non-ASCII digits. I'd probably go for a hexadecimal format.

Maybe you can pass `FREByteArray` instead of the String? This should be even faster, as the passed data are half as long (a java `Character` takes two bytes) and you could use `ByteBuffer.getDouble()` without any parsing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I tried both suggestions but again it was too slow, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong with extension, but here are results:

When I used FREByteArray, for 2048 elements it lasted about 900ms, here is the [code](http://pastebin.com/zwhnfZbR) 

And about longBitsToDouble, I didn't implement everything, but I tried to pass Longs packed in String to extension, and then use longBitsToDouble on constant dummy Long, like [this](http://pastebin.com/Ax3gTzJp), and it took 300-400ms for 2048 elements, which is not good enough for my needs. Thanks again for your tips :)

Comment: @StefanKostic In the code linked, you're reading a single `double` `n` times, each time doing a lot of needless work. This is a nonsense, it's slow and you're always reading the first byte! The loop must enclose a single line only (`real[i] = bb.getDouble();`). Concerning `longBitsToDouble`, it might be much slower on Android, I haven't try it. I'd try the `ByteBuffer` first.

Comment: Aaaaargh, I'm so sorry, don't know why, but i passed one ByteArray for each double instead of putting all doubles into one ByteArray, guess I was too tired :) 
Anyway, I tested now and results are really good - it approximately takes 10-15ms per iteration, so I have enough time for other calculations. Thank you very much once again, you saved me!